# database not read from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

my login page doesnt redirect me to the next webpage even if i inputted correct data on username and password.

when i check the config.inc and made it to config.php

it doesnt displays anything on the webpage.

any suggestions

CONFIG.INC

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root@localhost","","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

LOGINPROC PAGE

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('config.inc');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])) . "')");

// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
// Jump to secured page
header('Location: securedpage.php');
}
else {
// Jump to login page
header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

securedpage.php

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Secured Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is secured page with session: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b>
<br>You can put your restricted information here.</p>
<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is anything being output by `config.inc`?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO no output on config.inc

Comment: kindly check my new post code sir thanks

Comment: In your config file, you are using MySQLi functions to connect to the database; however, in your login page, you are using the old mysql_ functions, not sure if that will cause a problem, but it is best to stay consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure nothing is output before the header function, including any white space in your PHP file and any included PHP files

Answer (score 0):

Also check the files for any BOM unicode, this is usually an option in the editor applications , I would suggest you to comment the header function and use a echo to check if the if or the else are being done

Comment: what is the header function ser? im sorry i just started yesterday in php

Answer (score 0):

does your form in the same login page or a separate page? if it's in the same login page, try using an `if ($_POST['submit'])` then run your code. if it's in a separate page make sure in your form action you have the path for the login page.

Comment: kindly check my new post code sir thanks